# jQuery detect if input is filled

Tags: jquery, if-statement, input

I created this function which animates label when input has focus.

```
$("input").on("focus", function () {
  $(this).siblings().animate({
    top: "-20",
  }, 70, function() {
  });
});
```

I would like animate it back if input stays unfilled.

[Here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zqvyyM) is my codepen

Comment: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/VavqJL

Answer (score 4):

```
$("input").on("focus", function () {
  $(this).siblings().animate({
    top: "-20",
  }, 70, function() {
  });
});

$("input").on("blur", function() {
  if( $(this).val().length == 0 ) {
    $(this).siblings().animate( {
      top : "0"
    });
  }
});
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/VavgLv

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest:

```
$("input").on({
  // using an Object with event-names as the
  // keys, linking to the functions
  // to handle those events:
  'focus': function() {
    $(this).siblings().animate({
      'top': '-20',
    }, 70);
  },
  // handling the 'blur' event on the input:
  'blur': function() {
    // if the value of the <input> element, with
    // leading and trailing white-space removed,
    // is equal to the default value of the <input>
    // (the value it held on page-load)
    // we animate the 'top' CSS property back to 0:
    if (this.value.trim() == this.defaultValue) {
      $(this).siblings().animate({
        'top': 0
      }, 70);
    }
  }
});
```

```js
$("input").on({
  'focus': function() {
    $(this).siblings().animate({
      'top': '-20px',
    }, 70);
  },
  'blur': function() {
    if (this.value.trim() == this.defaultValue) {
      $(this).siblings().animate({
        'top': 0
      }, 70);
    }
  }
});
```

```css
div {
  margin: 1em;
  padding: 0;
  border-radius: 1em;
  position: relative;
}
label {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="">
  <fieldset>
    <div>
      <label for="input1">input 1</label>
      <input type="text" id="input1">
    </div>
    <div>
      <label for="input2">input 2</label>
      <input type="text" id="input2">
    </div>
    <div>
      <label for="input3">input 3</label>
      <input type="text" id="input3">
    </div>
    <div>
      <label for="input4">input 4</label>
      <input type="text" id="input4">
    </div>
    <div>
      <label for="input5">input 5</label>
      <input type="text" id="input5">
    </div>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/pjtzxp66/).

The reason for checking if the current value is equal to the default-value (`this.value.trim() === this.defaultValue`) is to ensure that the `<label>` returns to its original position if the user entered no value, and we trim that string (removing leading and trailing white-space) as a check against users entering only white-space in that field.

With some restrictions this can be partially achieved using pure CSS; the caveats for this are:

- the `<input>` elements must precede the `<label>` element in the mark-up,
- the `<input>` elements must have both a `required` attribute and an attribute, such as `minlength`, `maxlength` or `pattern` in order to identify a 'valid' entry

With those restrictions in mind, though, the following is possible:

```
<form action="">
  <fieldset>
    <div>
      <!-- the <input> here precedes the <label> in order that
           the <label> can be styled based on the state of the
           <input> element.

           Also the 'minlength' attribute is present, to allow
           CSS to determine whether the entered value is
           valid or invalid, with the required attribute -->
      <input type="text" id="input1" required minlength="5" />
      <label for="input1">input 1</label>
    </div>
    <!-- repeated elements removed for brevity -->
  </fieldset>
</form>

/* Here we style the <label> element's default state,
   and the state when it follows an invalid <input>: */
label,
input:invalid + label {
  position: absolute;
  top: 1px;
  left: 0.5em;
  /* we set the transition for the element, to work on
     the 'top' property, to take effect over 0.7 seconds
     with a linear progression from start to end: */
  transition: top 0.7s linear;
  background-color: #fff;
}

/* Here we set the styles for the <label> when the preceding
   <input> has focus, and when it has a valid entry, and is
   positioned above its preceding <input>: */
input:focus + label,
input:valid + label {
  top: -20px;
}
```

```css
div {
  margin: 1em;
  padding: 0;
  border-radius: 1em;
  position: relative;
}
label,
input:invalid + label {
  position: absolute;
  top: 1px;
  left: 0.5em;
  transition: top 0.7s linear;
  background-color: #fff;
  box-sizing: content-box;
  padding: 0;
}
input:focus + label,
input:valid + label {
  top: -20px;
}
```

```html
<form action="#">
  <fieldset>
    <div>
      <input type="text" id="input1" required minlength="5" />
      <label for="input1">input 1</label>
    </div>
    <div>
      <input type="text" id="input2" required minlength="5" />
      <label for="input2">input 2</label>
    </div>
    <div>
      <input type="text" id="input3" required minlength="5" />
      <label for="input3">input 3</label>
    </div>
    <div>
      <input type="text" id="input4" required minlength="5" />
      <label for="input4">input 4</label>
    </div>
    <div>
      <input type="text" id="input5" required minlength="5" />
      <label for="input5">input 5</label>
    </div>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/pjtzxp66/1/).

References:

- CSS:

  - [`:valid` and `:invalid` selectors](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors4/#validity-pseudos).
- JavaScript:

  - [`String.prototype.trim()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim).
- jQuery:

  - [`animate()`](http://api.jquery.com/animate/).
  - [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/).
  - [`siblings()`](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/).

Comment: HI Mr.David thomas,you  queried on post about "What have you tried what went wrong"  which is a common query to the beginners .. from there you know what comments faced from the Guy.i discussed to the Guy and Got clarity about his mistakes and make him admit . Please take a look in comment " 
Let us continue this discussion in chat" invitation by the Guy. i make him admit the Mistake .you may don't care about it & already forgot  but i felt it  he is disrespecting you.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35821885/get-an-attribute-of-an-element-that-have-an-attribute-that-is-equal-a-variable

Answer (score 0):

I'd use `focusout` event, it's the opposite, when input looses focus, [here's the snippet](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LNpMKP)

Here's the code:

```
$("input").on("focus", function () {
  $(this).siblings().animate({
    top: "-20",
  }, 70);
}).on("focusout", function () {
  if( $(this).val().length == 0 ) {
      $(this).siblings().animate({
         top: "0",
      }, 70);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The [focusout](https://api.jquery.com/focusout/) event occurs when an element (or any elements inside it) loses focus.

```
$("input").on("focusout", function() {
  if( $(this).val().length == 0 ) {
    $(this).siblings().animate( {
      top : "0"
    });
  }
});
```

Hope it helps as well :)

Comment: it's duplicate of mine answer below.

Comment: I didn't mean to copy or duplicate i've shared whatever i do have knowledge It should not be duplicate if you have given answer earlier then me ? sounds right ?