# Get an attribute of an element that have an attribute that is equal a variable

Tags: jquery

Let's suppose that I have this:

```
<a href="/index" data-title="Home">LINK</a>
<a href="/page2" data-title="Another Page">LINK</a>
```

and I have to get the `data-title` from the `a` tag that has a `href` that is equal to the `location.pathname`.

How do I do this with jQuery?

Comment: I didn't tried anything, @DavidThomas. I didn't knew how to do it.

Comment: What do you mean  @  Sentence " You didn't know how to highlight something with CSS, man. Please, if you don't know what to say, don't say it" ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105473/discussion-between-igor-and-n-v-prasad).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use code below:

```
$('a[href="' + location.href + '"]').attr('data-title')
```

See working code sample below, but `location.href` replaced to `/index` to show that snippet works well:

```js
alert($('a[href="' + '/index' + '"]').attr('data-title'))
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="/index" data-title="Home">LINK</a>
<a href="/page2" data-title="Another Page">LINK</a>
```